# In Behaviors Plugin 0.5.3 for Jira 5.1.8, I am unable to make reporter field as Read-Only?

Tags: java, jira

I am upgrading my Jira from 4.3.2 to 5.1.8. I have my reporter field as read-only field for couple of transitions.

I wanted to make this reporter field as read-only in Jira 5.1.8 also. But when I install compatible version for Jira 5.1.8 i.e. Behaviour Plugin 0.5.3. then reporter field or any other user picker is not made as read-only.

This is a Bug for Behaviour Plugin. 
Can anyone please tell me the workaround for this?

Any help will be appreciable...

Thanks in Advance.

Renu

Comment: This is not a real solution, but it might be useful until that bug will be resolved; create a "Velocity processed Message Custom Field (for edit)", add it to related screens, and set it default value as a jQuery script that makes reporter field to read-only.

Comment: Hi Kuf, Thanks for the updated script. I have checked but using your updated script reporter is made as Read Only on the create issue screen & edit issue screen but not for custom screen we have created. Can you please suggest why this is happening? Actually I wanted to make Reporter field read-only only for some transitions. I can make this using Jira Behaviors Plugin but this plugin is not working for Jira 5.1.8

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

How are you applying this? when running on the browser console, this should do the job:

```
AJS.$("#reporter-field").attr("disabled", true);
```

but when entering it to a field description use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
    AJS.$("#reporter-field").attr("disabled", true);
  });
</script>
```

You can apply this script in the following ways:

- go to  `View Field Configuration` and edit the `reporter` field and add this code as description.
- add it to a custom field description. this custom field should be present on every screen that the `reporter` field is at.
- add it to the `Announcement Banner` description

That will make the `reporter` field to be read only in all the screens. To disable the quick edit option, add this to the `Announcement Banner` description:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
    AJS.$("#reporter-val").removeClass("editable-field inactive");
    AJS.$("#reporter-val .icon-edit-sml").remove();
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT**

To limit this only for specific transitions you can either:

- add a custom field only to the specific transition screen and add it the script  to it's description.
- execute the script only on specific transition screen:

for example, to apply it only to `Resolve Issue`:

```
if (AJS.$("#workflow-transition-5-dialog .aui-popup-heading").text().indexOf("Resolve Issue") >= 0) {
    AJS.$("#reporter-field").attr("disabled", true);;
}
```

---

**original post**

You can achieve this easily by using jQuery. In the custome filed page, click `Edit` on the desired field, than under `description` enter the jQuery code, something like:

To disable the field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
    AJS.$("#customfield_10001").attr("disabled", true);
  });
</script>
```

To make it read only:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
    AJS.$("#customfield_10001").attr("readonly", true);
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT**

I've just noticed that you meant to disable `reporter`, which is not a custom field, and there can't add `description` to it.

As a workaround, you can create a custom field, doesn't matter which (if you allready have one in your page it will do the trick), and just swap `#customfield_10001` for `reporter`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
    AJS.$("#reporter-field").attr("disabled", true);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: We can add description to JIRA fields too and apply javascript also from field configuration .

Comment: Hi,I have tried the above solution but still no luck. I am unable to make reporter read only.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the reporter field as readonly in behaviours plugin . I guess this is a bug in the plugin . What i would suggest you is write a groovy script which will add a helptext to the reporter field using setHelpText(String helptext). the help text will be the below javascript . You will need to escape it as a string :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
        AJS.$("#reporter-field").attr("disabled", true);
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Mizan,

I checked your script but sometimes it is not working.For some screen it is hiding reporter field.

Can you please tell why it is happening? & I want this for some transitions if I apply it on description it will be applied globally.

Thanks & Regards,

Renu

Comment: Apply it in behaviours not field configuration. get object of your field in the script and add helptext to it .where your javascript will be an argument to the method. You will need to escape the script to String format