# How to make a JIRA Number Field read-only?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

As described in the title, I am looking for a smart, safe and efficient way to set a **Number Field** in JIRA to **Read-Only**. Below is a short list of approaches, guides and plugins used in an attempt to achieve this.

- Installed and deployed the [Behaviours Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.plugin.Behaviours)

  - This resulted in form permission errors all over JIRA setting some of the most basic and editable fields to non-writeable. Further investigation revealed that this is a known issue that will not be fixed anytime soon.
- I have gone up and down the options for JIRA's existing [Field Behaviour](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Specifying+Field+Behaviour) and it simply does not offer the option to set a field to read-only.

  - Hiding is not an option, as the field needs to be visible (more about that below).
- A potential option would be to create a new [Screen Scheme](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/113437/how-to-set-some-fields-as-read-only-after-submit-an-issue?page=1#113465) that simply excludes this field from the edit screen.

  - Associating new Screen Schemes with our current project would be a small disaster as many other projects are dependent and shared. Hence making the field read-only or admin-writeable-only would be a much better solution in this instance.

Regarding the Custom Field:
I created a post function in the workflow of our current project that will increase a Custom Number Field by increments of 1 every time an issue/task/bug is reopened. In essence, I am tracking the numbers of reopens. Which brings me to the reason for my *read-only* requirement. Developers shouldn't be able to change the value of this field as it would throw off statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery to make the field read only, add to the field description :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
    AJS.$("#customfield_10000").attr("readonly", true);
  });
</script>
```

change `customfield_10000` to your custom field id. You can find this id by viewing the issue edit page source and checking which id does it have.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495618/how-to-hide-some-issue-link-types-in-the-issue-link-pop-up-window-for-jira-5-1-8) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316021/in-behaviors-plugin-0-5-3-for-jira-5-1-8-i-am-unable-to-make-reporter-field-as#answer-14334998) answers and this for more details.

**[UPDATE]**

**To disable the  hover-to-edit function as well**, you can add the following script to jira's `Announcement Banner` , this way it will run on every screen:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
    AJS.$("#customfield_10000").attr("readonly", true);
    AJS.$("#customfield_10000").removeClass("editable-field inactive");
    AJS.$("#customfield_10000 .icon-edit-sml").remove();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question! I added the script and it _partially_ works. The field remains editable when using the hover-to-edit function. Would we have to disble the jQuery hover functionality to achieve that?

Comment: answer updated , add this script to jira's `Announcement Banner, that should do the trick.`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added that script to the Announcement Banner, however, inline/hover-editing still overwrites the data in the fields. Any other suggestions I could follow?

Comment: sorry about that, my bad, added new script to my answer

Comment: For some reason this function only worked for hover-to-edit. I had to combine the function from JIRA's site to get both. https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/How+to+Disable+Inline+Edit+for+Assignee+Field

Answer (score 0):

Stopping inline editing from working is trickier it seems. What stopped the Behaviours plugin working for you, do you have a link to the known issue? The one option you haven't listed is to create a new custom field type that extends the familiar Number custom field type but in its velocity template restricts who can edit the field. This kind of customization is documented at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Creating+a+Custom+Field+in+JIRA and also in Practical JIRA Plugins (O'Reilly)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a link to the issue, but I can describe it for you. I used the plugin to set behavior to read-only for a custom number field. The side effect of this caused the assignee and reporter fields to be NOT inline editable. I will look into your provided link and see if it gets me there. THanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Use the "disabled" keyword in your form item. E.g.
Code:
`<input type="text" name="foo" value="bar" disabled>`

Comment: Looking into this right now and testing. Will post back with results!